# About the integral of $\frac{\sin(ax)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}$ over the positive real line

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How could I compute the following integral: $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {{{\sin (ax)} \over {{e^{2\pi x}} - 1}}dx} $$
? Thank you.